# Why is the text size not increasing?

Tags: jquery, html, css

For some reason my text wont respond to any size values:

This is what I have:

```
<section id="center" class="theLogo">
    <div id="responsiveLogo">September</div>
  </section>


<script src="js/fittext.js"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery("#responsiveLogo").fitText(1,{ minFontSize:'60px'});
  </script>
```

CSS

```
#center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#responsiveLogo {
    font-family: "utopia-std",sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2em;
    }
```

The 'September' is the one that's not responding. It should be much bigger.

[Live version here](http://septemberstudio.co.uk/)

Comment: You have an inline style on you main container `<section id="center" class="theLogo" style=" font-size: 125px; top: 257.5px; left: 594.5px;"></section>`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this ?

```
#center span {
    font-size: 67px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you listed isn't what's on your website.

You mislabeled your ID either change your JavaScript to:

```
jQuery("#center").fitText(1,{ minFontSize:'60px'});
```

Or change your HTML to:

```
<section id="responsiveLogo" class="theLogo" style="top: 180px; left: 247px; font-size: 73.9px;"> ....Span Soup....</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#responsiveLogo {
    font-family: "utopia-std",sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700px;
    font-size: 2em;
    }
```

try with **px**